# Why is an error interrupting a Xdebug session?

Tags: php, symfony, intellij-idea, xdebug, api-platform.com

I'm debugging a PHP application (Symfony 6.2) using Xdebug via IntelliJ. Debugging session start just fine and breakpoints are being hit. I'm happy with that. The PHP service runs within a docker container and remote debugging works, obviously.

Until an exception is thrown, printed in the stdout:

```
In ExceptionConverter.php line 32:
  An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked                         

In Exception.php line 28:
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked  

In Connection.php line 32:
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked
```

The IntelliJ debugging tool window prints:

```
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

How can I avoid interrupting the debugging session?

I expect Xdebug not to be interrupted by an exception thrown by another process.

Comment: Exit code 137 can indicate that the process is running out of memory. Perhaps Xdebug is sending more data than it can handle. Does it happen for every exception, or just in some cases?

Comment: It happens for every exception.

Comment: Are you sure it's a different process that exits with the exit code? It must be the same one. You can confirm that by looking at the [Xdebug remote log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs) - if you see the `status="stopping"` even there, you can be sure that the process that you were debugging has stopped